# ScrollViewProxy.scrollTo scrolls to wrong position when called from onAppear

Tags: ios, swiftui

iOS 16.2, Xcode 14.2

I'm trying to scroll to a specific item in a List when I enter a view. I tried using onAppear that calls proxy.scrollTo. I added the sleep to make it work more often, and it *usually* scrolls down to show the item, but sometimes it only scrolls partway and the selected item isn't visible. Even after sleeping 3s, the scroll doesn't always go to the right place. However, tapping the CardView always scrolls to the right position.

So, I see that https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/scrollviewreader has a new note: "You may not use the ScrollViewProxy during execution of the content view builder; doing so results in a runtime error. Instead, only actions created within content can call the proxy, such as gesture handlers or a view’s onChange(of:perform:) method." I guess that might explain the behavior I'm seeing, but then how can I reliably scroll to the item on initial render?

```
struct CardGroupView: View {
    var listItems: [ListItem]

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            ScrollViewReader { proxy in
                List(listItems) { _ in
                    CardView()
                        .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
                        .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            // this works 100% of the time
                            proxy.scrollTo("df87ea1b-eae8-4989-a126-df49b8570a8d")
                        }
                }
                .listStyle(.plain)
                .onAppear {
                    // do in a Task and sleep to rule out render timing issue
                    Task { @MainActor in
                        try await Task.sleep(for: .milliseconds(3000))
                        // this doesn't always work -- sometimes it scrolls only partway to the item
                        proxy.scrollTo("df87ea1b-eae8-4989-a126-df49b8570a8d")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct CardView: View {
    var isCurrent: Bool

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 90) {
            // some random stuff, it doesn't matter what's here
            Divider()
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(isCurrent ? Color.blue : Color.green)
                .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So painful .. tried many different things, including replacing Task with DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter, and using onChange in addition to onAppear. In each case, it either occasionally scrolls to the wrong position, or it crashes (this error: https://useyourloaf.com/blog/swiftui-scrollviewproxy-crash/). So instead, I've given up on using List and replaced it with a ScrollView/ForEach, where the scrolling works perfectly. In general it seems that ScrollViewReader+List don't play well together. I didn't give up much by switching away from List (apart from it being refreshable).